# Standing wave is transverse but can it also occurs in longitudinal wave?

Tags: waves

Imagine 2 people each holding onto different end of a slinky and both of them starts synchronisation swinging up and down creating a standing wave also a transverse wave. But what about standing wave in longitudinal wave? I can only imagine pinching a spring between a thumb and index finger.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/standw.html

Comment: I created a crude visualization to help you understand the motion better. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/naneaeezlz  It's not entire accurate with regards to the movement but it should be enough to help you wrap your mind around it. I can make a more accurate version if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, that was a bit terse.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Sound/tralon.html#c1

Look at the diagram in the link. The point of a longitudinal standing wave is that a region of compression changes from compression to expansion but this pattern of compression and expansion does not move.

If you were to plot the density as a function of time, then at each point it would go up and down in a regular pattern, and the magnitude of the variation would be constant.

This makes the most sense in a linear medium where the wave can be viewed as a sinusoid. The definition of a standing wave becomes more difficult if the medium is non linear.